# Relation between $\mathrm{Pic}^\natural_{X/S}$ and two notions of rigidification

Tags: reference-request, connections, line-bundles, picard-group

Let $X/S$ be a relative curve (perhaps with more adjectives). I have come across a few instances of rigidifying and rigidificators, which I would like to understand better.

In [Liu-Lorenzini-Raynaud](http://virtualmath1.stanford.edu/%7Econrad/BSDseminar/refs/BSDAT.pdf) (p447) or [Guignard's article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.02243) (p18) there is the notion of rigidified line bundle:
Let $i:Y \hookrightarrow X$ be a closed subscheme which is finite and locally free over $S$.
A $Y$-*rigidified line bundle* is a pair $(\mathcal{L},\alpha)$ where $\mathcal{L}$ is a line bundle on $X$, and $\alpha: \mathcal{O}_Y \to i^*\mathcal{L}$ is an isomorphism.

Another way one could rigidify a line bundle is to take pairs $(\mathcal{L}, \nabla)$, where $\mathcal{L} \xrightarrow{\nabla} \Omega_{X/S}\otimes\mathcal{L}$ is a connection.
In both cases we would define isomorphism of pairs in the obvious way. With some restrictions and caveats, we can define two modifications of the (relative) Picard group/functor:
$$\mathrm{Pic}_S(X,Y) = \text{isomorphism classes of Y-rigidified line bundles},$$
$$\mathrm{Pic}^\natural_S(X) = \text{isomorphism classes of line bundles with connection}.$$

In Mazur-Messing (p13,26) or [Cais's article](https://arxiv.org/abs/0909.1849) there is another notion of rigidification:
Let $F, G$ be two $S$-group schemes. A *rigidified extension* of $F$ by $G$ is a pair $(E, \sigma)$, where $E$ is an extension (of fppf sheaves of abelian groups over $S$) given by
$$0 \to G \to E \to F \to 0$$
together with a morphism from the 1st infinitesimal neighborhood of the identity of $F$
$$\mathrm{Inf}^1_S(F) =: F_1 \xrightarrow{\sigma} E$$
which projects to the canonical immersion $F_1 \to F$.

From this second notion emerges rigidified Ext functors $\mathrm{Extrig}_S, \mathcal{E}xtrig_S$, and then a close relationship between
$\mathcal{E}xtrig(\cdot, \mathbb{G}_m)$ and $\mathrm{Pic}^\natural_S$ (which I don't yet understand). I think $\mathrm{Pic}^\natural$ is related to Deligne-Beilinson cohomology, and may in other contexts be referred to as the analytic Picard group $\mathrm{Pic}^{an}$. But I'm in a lot of unfamiliar territory.

It seems plausible to me that there is some way of expressing one rigidification of line bundles in terms of the other, and I would be delighted to be able, but I haven't figured out how to do so.

My questions:

- Is there a relationship between these two methods of rigidifying line bundles, or the two modified Picard groups?
- Is there a relation between a $Y$-rigidified line bundle and a rigidified extension, or is the terminology merely coincidental?

Any help would be much appreciated.